# How can I convert an arbitrary number of columns in a Spark dataframe from Timestamps to Longs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm writing this in Scala and am using Spark 1.6, and don't have the option to switch to a newer version. I'm attempting to merge two dataframes, one pulled in from Avro files on a Hadoop cluster and one pulled in from a Teradata db. I can read them both in just fine, and both are guaranteed to have the same column names in the same order, but when I try to merge them using

```
 data1.unionAll(data2)
```

I hit an error because Avro converts timestamps to longs, so the datatypes of the two don't match for those fields. This process will be repeated several times and I know there will always be at least one timestamp field in the tables, but there can possibly be more and I will not always know their names, so I'm attempting to make a general method that will convert any arbitrary number of columns from timestamp to longs. This is what I have so far:

```
def transformTimestamps(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val convert_timestamp_udf = udf((time:Timestamp) => time.getTime())
    df.dtypes.foreach { f => 
        val fName = f._1
        val fType = f._2
        if (fType == "TimestampType:) {
            println("Found timestamp col: " + fName)
            df.withColumn(fName, convert_timestamp_udf(df.col(fName)))
            df.printSchema()
        }
    }
   return df
}
```

With the printouts I can tell that the method is correctly recognizing only the timestamp columns, but the .withColumn transformation is not working. Printing the schema in the next line does not show the updated column. Additionally, I've also tried creating an entirely new column for the transformed values, and it is not added to the df either. Can anyone spot why this isn't working?

Comment: You could at least posted a code that compiles ! It's `DataFrame` not `Dataframe` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following line is just `transformation`

```
df.withColumn(fName, convert_timestamp_udf(df.col(fName)))
```

which would not be reflected on the original `dataframe` until an `action` is performed. Assignment would work as an action so you can create a temporary `dataframe` and assign to it in the loop as

```
   def transformTimestamps(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
      val convert_timestamp_udf = udf((time:Timestamp) => time.getTime())
      var tempDF = df
      df.schema.map(f => {
        val fName = f.name
        val fType = f.dataType
        if (fType.toString == "TimestampType") {
          println("Found timestamp col: " + fName)
          tempDF = tempDF.withColumn(fName, convert_timestamp_udf(df.col(fName)))
          tempDF.printSchema()
        }
      })
      return tempDF
    }
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: With all due respect, this code is incorrect to start with. But I'm still not sure I get the solution that you have given.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. It's DataFrame not Dataframe. So you just copied it and which is the source of the problem. The OP kind a mislead you. It can happen to anyone :)

Comment: yeah you are right. I copy pasted. and i didn't bother to test as well because I was certain with what mistakes he was making of not returning the changed dataframe. his mistake was that the returned dataframe was the original dataframe he passed to the function. @eliasah I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid using mutable `var` is that you can perform the type conversion by assembling a list of columns of `TimestampType` and going through the list via `foldLeft` with your conversion UDF:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

val df = Seq(
  (1, Timestamp.valueOf("2016-05-01 11:30:00"), "a", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-06-01 07:00:30")),
  (2, Timestamp.valueOf("2016-06-01 12:30:00"), "b", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-07-01 08:00:30")),
  (3, Timestamp.valueOf("2016-07-01 13:30:00"), "c", Timestamp.valueOf("2017-08-01 09:00:30"))
).toDF("id", "date1", "status", "date2")

val convert_timestamp_udf = udf( (time: Timestamp) => time.getTime() )

// Assemble all columns filtered with type TimestampType
val tsColumns = df.dtypes.filter(x => x._2 == "TimestampType")

// Create new dataframe by converting all Timestamps to Longs via foldLeft
val dfNew = tsColumns.foldLeft( df )(
  (acc, x) => acc.withColumn(x._1, convert_timestamp_udf(df(x._1)))
)

dfNew.show
+---+-------------+------+-------------+
| id|        date1|status|        date2|
+---+-------------+------+-------------+
|  1|1462127400000|     a|1496325630000|
|  2|1464809400000|     b|1498921230000|
|  3|1467405000000|     c|1501603230000|
+---+-------------+------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    val index = ss.sparkContext.parallelize( Seq((1,"2017-5-5"),
  (2,"2017-5-5"),
  (3,"2017-5-5"),
  (4,"2017-5-5"),
  (5,"2017-5-5"))).toDF("ID", "time")

val convert_timestamp_udf = udf((time:Timestamp) => time.getTime())

val newDF = index.withColumn("time", convert_timestamp_udf($"time"))
newDF.show
```

Comment: This won't work for the OP as he has an arbitrary number of timestamp columns

Comment: you are right.I miss the arbitrary number  of timestamp .